# Can´t validate type of data on update/findOneAndUpdate mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In create, the validation works fine and it will throw validation error if missing required or wrong type.

However, when I try to update or findOneAndUpdate it only validates wether any required is missing, but it doesn´t validate the type. At the moment I can update the name property to a number and no validation error happens. Any idea on what to do?

```
mongoose.set('runValidators', true);
```

```
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', {
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  morada: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
})

module.exports = Post
```

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(req.params, req.body, {new: true});     
    res.json(post)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly define the `Post` model using a [mongoose schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). Something like the following:

```
const PostSchema = {
    nome: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    morada: { type: String, required: true, trim: true}
};

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

If that doesn't work, you could use a [`pre`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) function on the schema. The [`pre`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) function allows you to run code before certain actions (e.g. save) where you can do things like more granular data validation.

For example:

```
Post.pre("save", function(next, done) {
    let self = this;

    if (invalid) {  // Replace 'invalid' with whatever checking needs to be done
        // Throw an Error
        self.invalidate("nome", "name must be a string");
        next(new Error("nome must be a string"));
    }

    next();
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your coment. I could not solve the issue with the schema. Regarding the pre function, I could not find any documentation that shows an example on how to to validate the data type for an update function. So Im´m still completely lost.

Comment: Have you had a read through this? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Comment: Yes, I did understand the concept of it, but I am still a begginer so I don´t quite understand how to make the condition work. In your code, could I replace invalid eith something like if (nome !== string)? I don´t understand how to write a condition for a property inside the schema.

Comment: You could try doing something like `if (!(nome instanceof String))`